# Comment turned Invisible

Tags: functions, comments, errors

Please help me with this problem.

People can comment, and the database shows the commented data. but the website is not displaying them. They are just showing blank space. (Just the username of the commenting person)

I thought it was due to comment plugin bug, so I deactivated it the native WordPress comments also working in the same way.

Comment: ( I tried disabling various plugins and it didn't change the result)

Comment: I don't think this can be solved with just the information provided. E.g. is the comment text present but invisible e.g. it's in the raw HTML but can't be seen in the browser, or is it missing from the HTML? How are your comments being displayed in your theme?

Comment: It did work before and even after adding plugins like WP-rocket, it did work. 
And I disabled minifying CSS and JS in everywhere I saw(In Cloudflare or plugins).
Also, the HTML doesn't have the comments(I used inspect and it didn't show the comment data, but database have it, because when I click edit button as admin, I can see them)

Comment: It does display the user name and a black space where the comment was supposed to.
Except the comment text is not there.
Users can see someone commented, but they cant see what it is.
(sorry for the bad English)

Comment: Is the HTML text there on the page, just being set to an invisible color via CSS? Or is the text completely missing?

Comment: Completely missing. I tried with inspector to see if it's hidden. Unfortunately, it's not.
The website URL is
novels.audertist.com
it has a comment widget on the right side, so u can find post commencement easily.

Comment: how are your comments being displayed in your theme? If it worked in the past when did that change? Has it ever worked? There's no comments code in your question to debug, and no way for us to figure out the problem remotely. Descriptions of missing comment text aren't enough to solve the problem. Have you switched theme?